# Errors after Migrating from Localhost to Live Server - Strict Standards & Header Info

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been left scratching my head this evening. I have a site on a localhost that is working fine, however now when I am trying to migrate it to a live host I'm getting a few issues.

Along with the White Screen of Death, the 3 error messages that are currently coming up look like the following:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of uncode_slider::contentAdmin() should be compatible with WPBakeryShortCode::contentAdmin($atts, $content = NULL) in /home/website/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/uncode-core/vc_extend/init.php on line 631
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/website/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/uncode-core/vc_extend/init.php:631) in /home/website/public_html/wordpress/wp-login.php on line 390
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/website/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/uncode-core/vc_extend/init.php:631) in /home/website/public_html/wordpress/wp-login.php on line 403

I've just looking for other questions/answers but can't seem to get the fix.

It seems the 2 elements clashing are my theme (`UnCode`) and the Visual Composer plugin. Just wondering if anyone has encountered this before and how I can hopefully get around this without having to forfeit the theme or plugin. It works perfectly locally!

Comment: These just look like warnings, which can be safely turned off. Just add `error_reporting(0);` to your index.php file.

Comment: Hi FrankerZ, Thanks so much for the quick response! I added that code after my last line in my index.php file, however I still have the error coming up on my main screen, and also still the white screen. Such a pain!

Comment: Search your files for `error_reporting(`. My guess is it's being overwritten later in the script.

Answer (score 0):

- First check your database under wp_options and check that you have changed siteurl and home to the new url.
- Try to deactivate your plugins by renaming them in plugins folder until you can access the wp-admin page.
- Then go to Settings -> Permalinks and click Save Changes.